# Создание Zip с файлам на чужом сервере

Tags: php, zip

Вот такое ТЗ:
Есть список ссылок на файлы, получая по ссылке за один цикл цыкла `foreach`.
мне нужно записать эти файлы на zip архив и предложить пользователю его скачать.
как это сделать? При том, что все ссылки указывают на другой сервак.
вот что получилось у меня

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('/user/'.$id.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($response->data as $item) {
$zip->addFile("$item->images->standard_resolution->url");
echo $item->images->standard_resolution->url;
echo '<br>';
$zip->close();
```

Но никакого файла в папке `users` не создается`:(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В папке users ничего не создается потому что вы создаете архив в папке user.

Вам нужно добавить файл в архив а вы добавляете ссылки на него. Вам предварительно нужно скачать файл. Можно как-то так:

```
$img = '/my/folder/someimage.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($item->images->standard_resolution->url));
```

Можете использовать curl если вам он больше нравится.

Добавлять файл в архив нужно только после того как вы его скачаете.

```
$zip->addFile($img);
```